# Replace Value Nested List Comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am struggling to figure out how to mix nested list comprehension with a replacing
Here is an example of the nested for loops that I am trying to convert

```
array1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
array2 = [['a','b','c'],[7,4,1]]

for i in array1: 
    value=i[0] 
    for val2 in array2[1]: 
        if value==val2: 
            #convert i to array2[0][array2[1].index(val2)]
```

I've tried this but it just converts everything to ['a','b','c']

```
In [34]: [[x if x == y else array2[0] for y in array2[1]] for x in array1]

Out[34]:
[[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
 [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
 [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]]
```

The result I am expecting is

```
In[35]:array1
Out[35]: 
[['c',2,3],['b',5,6],['a',8,9]]
```

If list comprehension isn't the best way solve, this, I would appreciate that answer also. I could do this, but I don't think it's the most efficient way.

```
for ii in range(len(array1))
    value = array1[ii]
    ...
            array1[ii] = array2[0][array2[1].index(val2)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get what you want in one line:

```
[[[x]+z[1:] for z in array1 if z[0] == y][0] for x, y in zip(*array2)]
```

```
[['a', 8, 9], ['b', 5, 6], ['c', 2, 3]]
```

for loop version:

```
output = []
for i, x in enumerate(array2[0]):
    for y in array1:
        if y[0] == array2[1][i]:
            output.append([x]+y[1:])
output
```

Comment: Yeah the one-liner is like totally unmaintainable - an incomprehensible comprehension.

Comment: Op wanted the list comprehension version...@barny

Comment: Some people want to e.g. juggle knives, doesn’t make it a good idea. (Wasn’t my downvote, BTW)

Comment: @barny I agree with you. I know the pain to maintain "fancy" codes

Comment: I like your method. I agree, the loop version might be best. I recommend swapping the order of the loops so the order of output matches array1

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer when it does not even produce the expected output, before considering its inefficiency.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of readability. The nested list comp is excessive IMO. `array2` is really the wrong data structure for what it is doing, so my first inclination is to make it a dictionary/mapping, as that is how you are using it here.

```
array1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
array2 = [['a','b','c'],[7,4,1]]

conversion = {}
letter_list, num_list = array2
for num, letter in zip(num_list, letter_list):
    conversion[num] = letter

output = [
    [conversion.get(num, num) for num in num_list] for num_list in array1 
]

# [['c', 2, 3], ['b', 5, 6], ['a', 8, 9]]
```

Comment: I agree this is _much_ better than a one-liner. Well done!